# Roslyn, how to generate a c# class at build-time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, code-generation, roslyn

At build time, using Roslyn Compiler Platform, I want to read a POCO and generate a [EntityName]Metadata.cs and a [EntityName]DataMapper.cs and attach it to my csProject but i am having trouble understanding how exactly to get this done.

Does anyone have any pointers? 
This needs to work in MSBuild... should i look into building a Custom Tool? if so are there any good examples out there?

Comment: There is not specific support in Roslyn for this.

Comment: In a DNX (asp vnext) project you could implement an [ICompileModule](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/1.0.0-beta3/samples/HelloWorld/compiler/preprocess/HelloMetaProgramming.cs)